# How to change stacked rows order in WP Bakery?

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

The elements in the right columns stack on top of the left columns. I am trying to make it so the text box overlaps the images. I make the margins negative for the top section to overlap, which does it correctly. However, I have adjusted margins and nothing makes it so the bottom sections text box overlaps the right side image. How can I make it so the bottom section left column overlaps the right column (where the top section stays the same)?

[image: example of right columns stacked on top of left columns]

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into a css property called z-index. Maybe it will solve your problem.

Since CSS is read from left to right, it naturally stacks the last element on top of others. Index can reverse that. Just give your textbox a higher z-index.